# Need a bit of guidance in regards to this PNP transistor question

Tags: transistors, resistors, pnp

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7aR4D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hello!

I'm currently stuck trying to answer this question. The question asks for me to find the resistance of R2 for R1 to be at 4V when the PNP transistor has a beta of 250. My current train of thought was to substitute 4V as the voltage of **R1** and solve for current which gave me 80mA, then use **Ic = β/Ib** to calculate **Ib** which was 0.32mA. I also worked the emitter current, **Ie** to be approximately 79mA.

This is where I got stuck, I now know the current of R2 but I don't know the voltage or the resistance so I can't work out either of these values. Is there something I'm not considering here? Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm really confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Was the VBE given to you? If not, are you told the saturation current for the BJT?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage across R2 is going to be 6- Vbe if your transistor is working in linear region, where Vbe=~ 0.6v is the PN junction voltage to be overcome in order to make the transistor work.

So the voltage across R2 is VR2 = 6-0.6= 5.4V

With this value you can apply the formula R2 = VR2/Ib and you´ll find the resistor value.

Comment: If a given answer was helpful, you should give it an upvote accordingly :)